# Checking application environment within a function outside of index page

Tags: node.js

I'm using the Node.js passport module (local Strategy) and within my isLoggedIn method, I want to check if I'm using the development environment. If I am, then I want to just log myself in with the admin user account, if not, then it should redirect to the login page where a normal user would login as usual.

The reason for this, is that during development, I have to keep re-logging in over and over again every time I make a change to the code which is really time consuming.

Here's my code (some parts are removed for clarity)

**index.js**

```
require('./app/routes.js')(app, passport);
```

**app/routes.js**

```
module.exports = function(app, passport) {

    app.post('/search', isLoggedIn, function(req, res) {
        // redirect to search page etc...
    });
}

function isLoggedIn(req, res, next) {

    // I want to check here if I'm it's the development environment and not production
    // If it's development, then it should perform a database lookup and look up the
    // admin user's account, otherwise it should carry on and use the isAuthenticated 
    // method below.
    // I wanted to use app.get('env') but "app" isn't available here..


    // if user is authenticated in the session, carry on
    if (req.isAuthenticated())
        return next();

    // if they aren't redirect them to the home page
    res.redirect('/login');
}
```

**config/passport.js**

```
passport.use('local-login', new LocalStrategy({
        // by default, local strategy uses username and password, we will override with email
        usernameField : 'email',
        passwordField : 'password',
        passReqToCallback : true // allows us to pass back the entire request to the callback
    },
    function(req, email, password, done) { // callback with email and password from our form

        // find a user whose email is the same as the forms email
        // we are checking to see if the user trying to login already exists
        User.findOne({ 'local.email' :  email }, function(err, user) {
            // if there are any errors, return the error before anything else
            if (err)
                return done(err);

            // if no user is found, return the message
            if (!user)
                return done(null, false, req.flash('loginMessage', 'No user found with username \'' + email + '\'')); // req.flash is the way to set flashdata using connect-flash

            // if the user is found but the password is wrong
            if (!user.validPassword(password))
                return done(null, false, req.flash('loginMessage', 'Oops! Wrong password.')); // create the loginMessage and save it to session as flashdata

            // all is well, return successful user
            return done(null, user);
        });

    }));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the `isLoggedIn` function within the `module.exports` definition.  The function will then have access to the scoped `app` object and `isLoggedIn` will remain "private" to the outside consumer (since it doesn't return anything).

```
module.exports = function(app, passport) {

    app.post('/search', isLoggedIn, function(req, res) {
        // redirect to search page etc...
    });

    function isLoggedIn(req, res, next) {
        app.get('env');
        // ...
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks @dylants! Worked perfectly. :)